# How to create a Python dataclass with a prop that depends on the output from a default_factory

Tags: python, self, python-dataclasses, python-class

I'm trying to use the `dataclasses` `default_factory` field to dynamically add a property (`id`) while also still being able to create a subsequent property (`id_with_appended_str`) whose default value depends on the former property (`id`) already being created.

The subsequent property (`id_with_appended_str`) should also support being declared as a parameter (e.g.: `MyDataClass(id_with_appended_str="123"`). The subsequent property should also be of type `str`, not `Optional[str]`. These are some examples that get close to the desired intent:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Final
from uuid import uuid4


@dataclass
class MyDataClass1:
    id: Final[str] = field(init=False, default_factory=lambda: uuid4().hex)
    id_with_appended_str: str = id + "something_appended"
    # or
    # id_with_appended_str: str = field(
    #     default_factory=(lambda id=id: id + "something_appended")
    # )

# A possible alternative
@dataclass
class MyDataClass2:
    id: Final[str] = field(init=False)
    id_with_appended_str: str

    def __post_init__(self):
        # Note this causes a linting error from reassigning a Final prop
        self.id = uuid4.hex
        self.id_with_appended_str = self.id + "something_appended"


def test_1():
    result = MyDataClass1()
    assert "something_appended" in result.id_with_appended_str


def test_2():
    result = MyDataClass1("123")
    assert result.id_with_appended_str == "123"
```

Comment: I believe that there's no way to achieve this without some introspection or metaclass hackery. But fwiw, the whole design sounds like a non-starter to me. If you want the described behaviour, you *don't* want a dataclass.